# Redefining static method in child class

Tags: java, inheritance, static, scjp

I would like to know the reason why this is first allowed  in Java (or oops in general)
  I remember that the static methods are common for both parent and child class

```
public class Redefine extends Parent{
    public static void test () {

    }
}


class Parent{
    public static void test () {

    }
}
```

**Q1 :** Since Overriding is not supported for static methods , how can both classe contain same methods ?

**Q2  :** If change the method in static to throw an exception not defined its not compiling.
      why is the case. Its obviously not overriding so i should be allowed to throw new exceptions right ?

```
public class Redefine extends Parent{
    public static void test () throws Exception{

    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**A1:**: `static` method are per-class. They have nothing to do with inheritance hierarchies in terms of polymorphism. So calling `Parent.test()` will call the parent method, while calling `Redefine.test()` will call the child.

**A2:** [JLS 8.4.8](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.4.8) writes:

> If a class declares a static method m, then the declaration m is said to hide any method m', where the signature of m is a subsignature (§8.4.2)  of the signature of m', in the superclasses and superinterfaces of the class that would otherwise be accessible to code in the class.
>
> A method declaration must not have a throws clause that conflicts (§8.4.6)  with that of any method that it overrides or hides; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.

Answer (score 4):

you arent overriding it, you are *hiding* it

http://faq.javaranch.com/java/OverridingVsHiding

what exception are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Q1: Static methods are not overridden, so these are two different methods with the same signature. One is called with Parent.test(), the other is called with Redefine.test()

Q2: Your method seems valid. What error do you get?

Comment: re: Q2: If you try the OP's version of Redefine.test() that is declared as `throws Exception` then you should get the compiler error `Exception Exception is not compatible with throws clause in Parent.test()`.